# How to plot Feature properties into a html div label using Leaflet and omnivore?

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have got some features in different GeoJSON files.

One of them includes Feature Collections (points and polyline) and the others just points.

I include those files into the Leaflet map using [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) plugin:

```
var track = omnivore.geojson("xxxx.geojson").addTo(map)
```

It is shown on the map as a polyline or a simple point, but I like to show a label including the "properties".

This is the `.geojson` file:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-100.0947, 56.1581]
    },
    "properties": {
        "object": "aaaa",
        "psn": "lipsum",
        "lat": "lipsum",
        "long": "lipsum"
    }
}
```

I cannot find the properties into the variable track after the GeoJSON file is loaded.

I try to show a label with object,psn,lat, lon

All the examples I found show how to do that with a JSON object as a variable, but the goal is: how to identify the properties of the every feature once it is loaded through omnivore?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possible solutions to access the properties of your GeoJSON Feature objects and use them to put in a label / popup / whatever:

1. Use a [`customLayer`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#custom-layers) as 3rd argument of `omnivore.geojson` call. That custom layer must be a Leaflet [GeoJSON Layer Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson), on which you can use its [`onEachFeature`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson-oneachfeature) option to access your Feature objects' properties as they are converted into Leaflet layers, and assign your labels from there.
2. Use the Omnivore's [`"ready"`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#async--events) event to execute a callback when it finishes loading and converting your GeoJSON data. In this callback, you can access the GeoJSON Layer Group returned by Omnivore, loop on its child layers with its [`eachLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layergroup-eachlayer) method. The Feature object from which each layer was converted can be accessed as the `feature` member of the layer (`layer.feature`), so you can access the properties with `layer.feature.properties`, and assign your labels.

In details:

1. Build your custom layer with `L.geoJSON` factory, with `null` initial data, but specifying its `onEachFeature` option and assigning your labels in there. Pass this custom layer to your `omnivore.geojson` call.

Live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/0cBem7HVZO0J2ByxBO6z?p=preview

```js
var customLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var properties = feature.properties;
    // Build the label / tooltip content…
    var content = [];
    for (var key in properties) {
      content.push(key + ': ' + properties[key]);
    }
    // Attach the label / tooltip to the built layer.
    layer.bindTooltip(content.join('<br>'), {
      permanent: true
    });
  }
}).addTo(map);

omnivore.geojson('demo.geojson', null, customLayer);
```

2. Call Omnivore the way you are currently doing, but attach a listener on its `"ready"` event. In the listener, loop through your `track` Layer Group using its `eachLayer` method, accessing the Features data with `layer.feature.properties` and creating your labels.

Live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/gT0bJxOUBJk6PVdLCk5F?p=preview

```js
var track = omnivore.geojson('demo.geojson').addTo(map);

track.on('ready', function () {
  track.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    var properties = layer.feature.properties;
    // Build the label / tooltip content…
    var content = [];
    for (var key in properties) {
      content.push(key + ': ' + properties[key]);
    }
    // Attach the label / tooltip to the layer.
    layer.bindTooltip(content.join('<br>'), {
      permanent: true
    });
  });
});
```